# Keep text clean from url

Tags: python

As part of Information Retrieval project in Python (building a mini search engine), I want to keep clean text from downloaded tweets (.csv data set of tweets - 27000 tweets to be exact), a tweet will look like:

```
"The basic longing to live with dignity...these yearnings are universal. They burn in every human heart 1234." ‚Äî@POTUS https://twitter.com/OZRd5o4wRL
```

or

```
"Democracy...allows us to peacefully work through our differences, and move closer to our ideals" ‚Äî@POTUS in Greece https://twitter.com/PIO9dG2qjX
```

I want, using regex, to remove unnecessary parts of the tweets, like URL, punctuation and etc

*So the result will be:*

```
"The basic longing to live with dignity these yearnings are universal They burn in every human heart POTUS"
```

and

```
"Democracy allows us to peacefully work through our differences and move closer to our ideals POTUS in Greece"
```

tried this: `pattern = RegexpTokenizer(r'[A-Za-z]+|^[0-9]')`, but it doesn't do a perfect job, as parts of the URL for example is still present in the result.

Please help me find a regex pattern that will do what i want.

Comment: If the whole line is a string, can't you just use `.split(",")[-1]` to get everything to the left of that comma in the example?

Comment: What's `RegexTokenizer` here? If you are using a particular library, you should mention it in your question. The Python standard module for regular expressions is called simply `re`.

Comment: Why do you consider punctuation unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

**Demo:**

```
import re

s1 = """"Democracy...allows us to peacefully work through our differences, and move closer to our ideals" ‚Äî@POTUS in Greece https://twitter.com/PIO9dG2qjX"""
s2 = """"The basic longing to live with dignity...these yearnings are universal. They burn in every human heart 1234." ‚Äî@POTUS https://twitter.com/OZRd5o4wRL"""    

def cleanString(text):
    res = []
    for i in text.strip().split():
        if not re.search(r"(https?)", i):   #Removes URL..Note: Works only if http or https in string.
            res.append(re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\.]", "", i).replace(".", " "))   #Strip everything that is not alphabet(Upper or Lower)
    return " ".join(map(str.strip, res))

print(cleanString(s1))
print(cleanString(s2))
```